# mongo shell search for value like "/"fubak@drooop.com"/"

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I may have let a bug loose on our code that essentially ruined some of our db data.

Every now and again we come across a username that has " " in his email so we need to fix this.

How can I search for a value like "/"fubak@drooop.com"/" in one field using my mongo shell?

I have been trying all the combinations I can think of like:

```
db.users.find(username: /"/" .* /)
```

and

```
db.users.find(username: //.*//)
```

or

```
db.users.find(username: /"".*/)
```

But nothing seems to work.

Comment: do you mean `\"`? use a backslash to escape the `"`.

Comment: the problem is that the fields already have quotes. so a normal search like: db.user.find() will return {username: "my.username@bla.com"} so what you proposed will match everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new RegExp('^".*')

This finds all the records that start with ".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not to sure which one is you problem, so the solutions to both possible scenarios with data in MongoDB like this:

```
{ "email" : "\"/\"fubak@drooop.com\"/\"" }
{ "email" : "/fubak@drooop.com/" }
{ "email": "\"blablabla@blip.ca\"" }
```

First document match:

```
db.problem.find({ email: /^\"/  })
```

Second document match:

```
db.problem.find({ email: /^\// })
```

Third document match

```
db.problem.find({ email: /^\"/ })
```

Do not know what you mean otherwise by "having quotes" as that is not valid JSON and by extension is also invalid BSON.

Comment: that didn't work. My values are exactly stored as "username" : "\"blablabla@blip.ca\"" and I need it to be "username" : "blablabla@blip.ca"

Comment: @Ricky okay then. Does the last one match. It does for me. And notice the "caret" `^` because your MongoDB performance will be terrible without that.

Comment: I've fixed this with RegExp (already answered) and sorry when I tried your solution I may have left the field name as email which was wrong so that might have been why it didn't work

Comment: @Ricky the point I have been generally making ( outside of the actual regex required, but the last example should suit ) is that if you do not "anchor" the the caret `^` then your MongoDB performance drops considerably. This may be a "get out of jail" operation for you specifically, but in general, un-bounded Regex operations in MongoDB are bad news. I just want people to be aware of that.

Comment: you are absolutely right! searching the beginning of a string is soo much faster than searching it all!

Comment: @Ricky some people might deem that information useful or even as the answer resolves your problem an acceptable answer. But that is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.users.find({ email: "(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*  })
```

This will match all documents which contains quotes in the email

Comment: try now.. db.users.find({ email: /".*?"/  })

Comment: sorry both worked but I had to replace users with user and email with username. In any instance, thank you for your help but I had already sorted it with the RegExP above :p